# UIPageViewController: Change color of page indicator/pagecontrol per page

Tags: objective-c, uipageviewcontroller, uipagecontrol

I am able to successfully change the color of PageControl/page indicator on UIPageViewController for the first page only. My use case requires each page to be a different color, requiring the PageControl/page indicator to match color with a page. I tried changing color based on the page index but it doesn't work.

Anyone know how to fix this?

```
- (PageContentViewController *)viewControllerAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
{


    if ([tutorialItems count] == 0) {
        return nil;
      }

      // Create a new view controller and pass suitable data.
      PageContentViewController *pageContentViewController
      = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PageContentViewController"];

      TutorialItem *tutorialItem = [tutorialItems objectAtIndex:index];
      pageContentViewController.imageFile = tutorialItem.tutorialImageFileName;
      pageContentViewController.titleText = tutorialItem.tutorialTitle;
      pageContentViewController.tutorialText = tutorialItem.tutorialText;

      int red = tutorialItem.tutorialRedKey;
      int green = tutorialItem.tutorialGreenKey;
      int blue = tutorialItem.tutorialBlueKey;

      pageContentViewController.pageIndex = index;

      tutorialBackgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:red/255.0f green:green/255.0f blue:blue/255.0f alpha:1.0f];

      pageContentViewController.tutorialBackgroundColor = tutorialBackgroundColor;

      UIPageControl *pageControl = [UIPageControl appearance];
      pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor blackColor];
      pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
      pageControl.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
      pageContentViewController.pageControllerColor = tutorialBackgroundColor;

      return pageContentViewController;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`appearance` proxy attributes only get set when a component is first added to the window. Changing an `appearance` attribute will not change it for already visible components. If you want to change the color of a component that is already on the screen, you will need to reference it and change the color on it directly, or remove it from the view hierarchy and re-add it.

[You can read the documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)

Relevant quote:

> iOS applies appearance changes when a view enters a window, it doesn’t
>   change the appearance of a view that’s already in a window. To change
>   the appearance of a view that’s currently in a window, remove the view
>   from the view hierarchy and then put it back.